# Convert Date from float64 to Year & Month Format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dateset where the date column (Year & Month only) are a float64 with the month represented as fraction the year (ex. June 2012 is displayed as 2012.6).

Can any suggest how I can convert this to show as month & date format (6-2012, 7-2012, etc)?

Thanks!

I assume the solution is with to_datetime but so far I haven't been able to convert the dates properly

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([2012.6]).astype(str), format='%Y.%m')
```

Output:

```
0   2012-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[2019.1, 2018.2], [2017.3, 2018.4]], columns = ["a", "b"])

        0       1
0  2019.1  2018.2
1  2017.3  2018.4

dataframe[a] = dataframe[a].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))

dataframe[a]

0   2019-01-01
1   2017-03-01

Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What this is doing is applying the function pd.to_datetime() to every value in the column converted to string type.

Hope it helps.